# Can I track the mobile number in website if some one opened website on their mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to track mobile number of their device if somebody opened the web site on their phones with 2G or 3G connection?
I mean by use of javascript OR php or any other web scripting language. But I believe Google adwords does the same thing

Comment: Nope, not possible. The phone number isn't sent to the website unless the user enters it somewhere.

Comment: why do you "believe Google adwords does the same thing"? i'm curious if you've noticed something google does; if adwords does indeed do such, it should be possible to do from any webpage....

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure, that this is not possible. Imagine the security/privacy breach it would represent if any site could just retrieve the phone number of each visitor.

Comment: But I believe Google adwords does the same thing

Comment: Can you provide a link describing some proof of what you claim?